# Clustering Data within a txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text

Created a batch script witch is going throw a log file and filters the necessary data that I need.

That is all really good but now I  would like to "cluster this data" so that I can save some time while creating this report since the log file that I get is 14.5mb and to process that takes too long.

So what I am doing so far is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=10 tokens=1,5,9 delims= " %%a in ("Log.txt") do (
    set "date=%%a"
    set "type=%%b"
    set "status=%%c"
    echo %%c|find "more">nul && set "status=Not granted"
    echo type: !type!
    echo status: !status!
    echo date: !date!
    echo.
)>>Test.txt
pause
```

Getting all the data each "type,data,status" individually. My dream would be to create something like that 
So only listing the type only once and if granted display the time stamp and if not the same

```
type: FSP
Granted:Granted 
date: 2016/03/15
date: 2016/03/15
....
Granted:Not Granted
date: 2016/03/23
date: 2016/02/1
```

So is there a chance that something like that could be accomplished ?